# std::back_inserter does not seem to work when applied to reference

Tags: cython

I am wanting to wrap `std::set_intersection`, but I am getting confusing results.

Code to reproduce error:

```
%%cython -a -+

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.algorithm cimport set_intersection
from libcpp.iterator cimport back_inserter

cdef vector[int] x, y, z

cdef intersection(vector[int]* i1, vector[int]* i2, vector[int]* o):
    set_intersection(i1.begin(), i1.end(), i2.begin(), i2.end(), back_inserter(o[0]))

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 3, 5]

intersection(&x, &y, &z)
print(z)
```

What I think `intersection` should do:

Take three `vector[int]` pointers and take the intersection of `i1` and `i2` and apply `push_back` to `o` the elements that are shared between `i1` and `i2`.

I get errors on compilation, however.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\iterator(41): error C2825: '_Container': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
C:\Users\<redacted>\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_0c03d6fb9770602e2805cbe448ec2c32fdd0e67d.cpp(2279): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &>' being compiled
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\iterator(41): error C2510: '_Container': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\iterator(41): error C2182: '_Val': illegal use of type 'void'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\iterator(46): error C2825: '_Container': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\iterator(46): error C2510: '_Container': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\iterator(46): error C2182: '_Val': illegal use of type 'void'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\iterator(64): error C2528: 'container': pointer to reference is illegal
```

If I modify the function a little bit by defining a vector in-scope, and copying the values it works just fine.

```
%%cython -a -+

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.algorithm cimport set_intersection
from libcpp.iterator cimport back_inserter

cdef vector[int] x, y, z

cdef intersection(vector[int]* i1, vector[int]* i2, vector[int]* o):
    cdef vector[int] o2
    set_intersection(i1.begin(), i1.end(), i2.begin(), i2.end(), back_inserter(o2))
    o[0] = o2

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 3, 5]

intersection(&x, &y, &z)
print()
print(z)
```

results in

```
[1, 3]
```

But, obviously I would like the intersection to fill the appropriate container, and avoid the extra copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> note: see reference to class template instantiation
> 'std::back_insert_iteratorstd::vector<int,std::allocator<int> &>'
> being compiled

Because `std::back_insert_iterator`'s template parameter is deduced to a reference which is wrong.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator

Instantiating it explicitly could solve the problem:
`back_inserter[vector[int]](o[0])`

Comment: I had no idea you could choose the template like that.